# Listview contact color change

Tags: android-listview

I have pick contact from system and display in a listview .but all the contact see in white color . I want to change display contact color black.Pls tell me solution. how can change listview contact color .

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"
 tools:context="com.cont.contact.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

  <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />
```

Comment: Which adapter do you use for your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a file my_styles.xml and save it in res/values.
- And add the following code in your xml file :

  ```
  <style name="ListFont" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
      <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
      <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
  </style>

  </resources>
  ```
- Add your style to your Activity definition in your AndroidManifest.xml as an android:theme attribute, and assign as value the name of the style you created. For example:

activity android:name="your.activityClass" android:theme="@style/ListFont">

Answer (score 0):

*Override the `getView` method of the `ListView`, find the contact view by its id and then change the color.*

**For example -**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.contact); 
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    return view;
  }
};
```